# ASP.NET Core: How to pass connection string to DBContext?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

There is the working example:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3132485/CRUD-Operation-using-ASP-NET-CORE-2-2-and-React-Re

I'd like to replace the hardcoded connection string in assembly with string from config. It is in the original example:

```
public partial class ContactDBContext : DbContext
{
    public ContactDBContext()
    {
    }

    public ContactDBContext(DbContextOptions<ContactDBContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Contacts> Contacts { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        {
            //#warning To protect potentially sensitive information 
            //in your connection string, you should move it out of source code. 
            //See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=723263 for guidance 
            //on storing connection strings.
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=yourservername ;
                                         Database=ContactDB;Trusted_Connection=True;");
       }
    }
}
```

I have added the code:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //...

    services.AddDbContext<ContactDBContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString(nameof(ContactDBContext))));//<------?

    //...
}
```

The string is read ok, but it is not used. The hardcoded string still used (see the first piece of code).

I use the context like

```
public class ContactService : IContactService
{
    public async Task<List<ContactModel>> GetContacts()
    {
        using (ContactDBContext db = new ContactDBContext())
        {

        //...
```

How to pass the connection string from app to EF context?

Comment: Remove the code from within the `OnConfiguring` which is overriding the connection set at startup

Comment: You're overwriting the connection string by setting it in `OnConfiguring`, since that occurs after `ConfigureServices`.

Comment: Ah, remove the code or remove function OnConfiguring at all?

Comment: Also it is possible that because you have a default constructor that the options are not being passed to the context and as such it will use the `OnConfiguring` because the builder options are not configured in that case

Comment: I have made 2 tests: removed the code in OnConfiguring , removed the function, run app - the same problem.

Comment: I would suggest removing the `OnConfiguring ` and testing again. If that fails then the problem is the default constructor

Comment: Pls see my prev comment, not fixed. How to fix the problem with default constructor?

Comment: Just remove the default constructor

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194182/discussion-between-oleg-and-nkosi).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are manually creating the instance of the context, the configuration applied at startup is not being injected into the context and instead it is using the `OnConfiguring` method.

That is why your configuration at start is not being applied.

Refactor the context to remove the default constructor and `OnConfiguring`

```
public partial class ContactDBContext : DbContext {
    public ContactDBContext(DbContextOptions<ContactDBContext> options)
        : base(options) {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Contacts> Contacts { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Next ensure that the context is injected into the desired dependent class

```
public class ContactService : IContactService {
    ContactDBContext db;

    public ContactService (ContactDBContext db) { 
        this.db = db
    } 

    public async Task<List<ContactModel>> GetContacts() {
        var contacts = db.Contacts;

        //...convert to models

        //...
    }
}
```

The configuration applied at startup should now be included when the container resolves the context for injection.

Reference [Configuring a DbContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext)